# Programmatically control the focus of a web camera

Tags: focus, controls, webcam

Who knows how i can programmatically control the focus of a web camera, logitech 910 for example. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from very very long ago, but for the benefit of others searching (and I searched for how to do this for about 2 days before finding this): you can do this using OpenCV. With OpenCV version 2.4.x and using Python version 2.7.x, you can do the following:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(28,focusvalue)
```

where focusvalue is whatever value you want to set the focus to.